# Purchase Xbox 360 content on Xbox.com without credit card on file

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

Is there any way to purchase Xbox 360 content on Xbox.com without a credit card on file? I'm getting an error that says "You have no valid payment options on file" and my only options are Change Payment Options and cancel.

If I click on "Change Payment Options", I'm shown a screen that only offers to "Add A New Credit Card".

This happens even if I have enough of a balance in my account to make the purchase, and even if the content I'm trying to purchase is free.

It's probably worth adding that I have no such issues with Xbox One content.

[image: Screenshot of the story page]

Comment: Wait.. What do you mean by 'balance'? (As in: The currency; USD? Bitcoins? Microsoft Points?) and what were you trying to buy?

Comment: I mean local currency from prepaid cards on my Xbox Live account, which in my case is USD. Microsoft Points don't exist anymore and as far as I know you can't use Bitcoins on Xbox Live.

Comment: Er.. [You can](http://blogs.microsoft.com/firehose/2014/12/11/now-you-can-exchange-bitcoins-to-buy-apps-games-and-more-for-windows-windows-phone-and-xbox/). But anyway - This sort of problem can usually be fixed by refreshing the page...

Comment: But that's not relevant to my question.

Comment: Is there any option to change to store credit?

Comment: No, the only option is Add A New Credit Card.

Comment: Er.. Have you checked your [balance](https://commerce.microsoft.com/PaymentHub?lang=en-us)? (That link should work as long as you're logged in)

Comment: Yes. And as I said in the question, I even have this problem for free content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there's finally official confirmation that the real answer is "You can't." From this [Major Nelson post](http://majornelson.com/blog/xbox-one-backward-compatibility/) about Xbox 360/Xbox One backwards compatibility:

> The Xbox 360 Marketplace and the Xbox One Store websites use different
>   architecture, so if you have credit but no payment option associated
>   with your account, you won’t be able to use the credit to purchase
>   Xbox 360 titles. You will have to add a payment option or purchase the
>   title using an Xbox 360 console.

Comment: I've been doing just that for months. At the very least, we can say they do not actually check the card (it was cancelled over 6 months ago, when I replaced it, and last used almost a year ago, to update xbox membership)

Comment: Thanks for this. Just wanted to confirm that "purchase the title using an Xbox 360 console" does still work (just bought Portal 2 on my old 360 using my MS credit). :)